# Audio​Buffer​Source​Node​.start() fails on Safari ONLY when started with an offset

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I am trying to start playing a buffer at a particular offset sometimes. I have an object that I create like this:

```
var directSource = AudioContext.createBufferSource();
```

Later on, after initializing it, I call:

```
directSource.start();
```

That works on all browsers.

The user can skip around, so I might stop that sound, and reinitialize everything (it runs the exact same code as the first time, except that it is passed an offset) and call start with:

```
directSource.start(0, offset);
```

This works on Chrome and Firefox, but that particular line causes an `InvalidStateError` on Safari, both on my MacBookPro and on an iPhone.

If I replace that line with:

```
directSource.start();
```

Then I DO NOT get the error.

I tested the AudioContext and it is definitely in the "running" state.

I put a `console.log()` just before calling `start()` to make sure I am not inadvertently calling it twice.

Can anyone help diagnose why Safari won't start at an offset? Is there somewhere else I can look for a clue about what it doesn't like.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem you encounter is that Safari is extremely picky in this case. The offset parameter needs to be less than or equal to the duration of the AudioBuffer in Safari.

The Web Audio spec says "offset is silently clamped to [0, duration]". (https://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#dom-audiobuffersourcenode-start-when-offset-duration-offset) But Safari is throwing an error instead.

You can avoid that by making sure that you clamp the value yourself.

```
bufferSource.start(
    0,
    Math.min(bufferSource.buffer.duration, offset)
);
```

I'm the author of a package called [standardized-audio-context](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context). It does not yet have a fix for this but I already created an [issue](https://github.com/chrisguttandin/standardized-audio-context/issues/519) for it. The goal of this package is to provide a version of the `AudioContext` which works almost the same in every browser in this little bug should definitely be handled as well.

Comment: I think the offset is already less than the duration - but I'll double check.

Comment: Yes, please let me know if this wasn't the cause of your problem.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem anymore - I'm not sure why, but I did put an extra `AudioContext.suspended` test in to fix another spurious bug, so I'm wondering if that fixed this issue, too. Thanks for your help!